# Suspiciously dying in one shot in online multiplayer Halo

Tags: halo

I was playing the original Halo online multiplayer mode and I was on full health and a player managed to kill me in one shot ..how is this possible?

I am suspecting cheating but am not sure because I am not extremely familiar with the game

Comment: It has been a long time since I played Halo multiplayer, but doesn't the game show your body when you die? Do you see any effects like a smoke cloud or bullet trail?

Comment: No..I can't see any effects

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Headshot with a sniper rifle, most probably. A plasma grenade stuck directly to you or a melee attack from the back would also do it.

Comment: How to dodge it?

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz If you know a sniper is firing at you, you can do what is calling strafing. In first-person shooters, strafing is where you constantly moving from side-to-side to make it more difficult to hit you. Takes a bit to get the hang of, but it's very useful in nearly any situation

Comment: Think in Halo1 also the Magnum (Pistol) is a 1 or 2 shot headshot kill.

Answer (score 1):

The CE magnum is overwhelmingly powerful and since it has a zoom you could have been headshot by it, as it could kill you in a single shot (if the other player landed it correctly.).